# AJAX запросы

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript

Странно работают `ajax` запросы. Есть функция, которая вызывается при нажатии на кнопку. Она в свою очередь делает два запроса к БД:

```
function nextQuestion() {
        makeRequestForCheck();
        makeRequestForQuestion();
    }

function makeRequestForCheck() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check_question.php",
        data: { user_id : $("input[name=user_id]").val(), quizid : $("input[name=quizid]").val(), 
                answer : function() {
                    arr = [];
                    $("input[name=variant]:checked").each(function() {
                        arr.push($(this).val());
                    });
                    return arr.join(",");
                } 
            },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(data) {

        },
        success: function(data){
            /* ... */
        }
    });
}

function makeRequestForQuestion() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_question.php",
        data: { user_id : $("input[name=user_id]").val(), quizid : $("input[name=quizid]").val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(data) {

        },
        success: function(data){
            /* ... */
        }
    });
}
```

Иногда получается так, что сначала делается запрос на следующий вопрос, а только потом - проверка. Никак не пойму, в чем может быть проблема.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужна *гарантированная* последовательность, то метод (функцию) `makeRequestForQuestion()` нужно вызывать из блока `success` функции `makeRequestForCheck()` (ну то есть внутри функции

```
success: function(date) {.... makeRequestForQuestion();}
```

). Если нужно, то можно ещё и в обработчике ошибки (если post-запрос не отработал).

Comment: Вроде сработало. А есть предположения, почему возникла такая ошибка?

Comment: Вероятно где-то есть какая-то очередь. Возможно обслуживаемая в порядке стэка. В фреймворке она или это особенности браузера... не рылся особо.